# Rubygems permission problem when using sudo

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I use `sudo` to install gems and update rubygems itself but this causes the problem of all new files in `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems` to be owned by `root:root` with a permission of `750`

This in turn causes most gems to fail to load.

For example, I recently updated rubygems and if I try `gem env` I get:

```
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:512:in `read': Permission denied - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/rubygems-update-1.6.2.gemspec (Errno::EACCES)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:512:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:116:in `load_gems_in'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:115:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:115:in `load_gems_in'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:112:in `reverse_each'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:112:in `load_gems_in'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:309:in `refresh!'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:67:in `from_gems_in'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:47:in `from_installed_gems'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1025:in `source_index'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/gem_path_searcher.rb:135:in `init_gemspecs'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/gem_path_searcher.rb:14:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:984:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:984:in `searcher'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:206:in `try_activate'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:57:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/config_file.rb:55
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:8
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/gem:9
```

The current workaround is to `chmod` all files to be readable by everyone but this is getting really annoying.

Some server stats:

`uname -a` gives

```
Linux HomeBox 2.6.35 28-server #49-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 1 14:55:37 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`sudo gem env` gives

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.6.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /home/nicklas/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

`ruby -v` gives

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [x86_64-linux]
```

I'd be happy to provide more info on the problem.

---

### Update

I just cleaned out all ruby and rubygems stuff and reinstalled it. Same problem.

Comment: If you used RVM you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: I used aptitude just like I do for everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Ubuntu at home too, and after many problems with using apt to install, I discovered [RVM](https://rvm.io).

RVM is super-simple to install, and gets you up and running quickly and easily. But once you start using it for a while, you'll discover that it is superior to any OS package system because it has features that allow you to:

- Install multiple versions of Ruby and JRuby and easily switch between them. I can just issue `rvm use 1.9.2`  or  `rvm use jruby-1.6.2` and my path is switched automatically and everthing just works.
- Install sets of gems into "gemsets" which allow you to use the same gems across multiple ruby versions, so you don't have to manually reinstall. Also, you can switch between gemsets so you can isolate experimental gem versions, etc.

My recommendation is to *uninstall* the native ruby package, and install RVM. You'll be glad you did.

Comment: I ended up doing this, rvm is very nice actually :)